# Custom encoding of GET data in a form

Tags: html, url, get

lets say I have this form

```
<form name="myform" action="/acms/test/multiselect/blah" action="GET">
<select name="mytextarea[]"  multiple="multiple">
    <option name="one"> one </option>
    <option name="two"> two </option>
    <option name="three"> three </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

if i submit this with all the options checked and look into the url, i see

```
?mytextarea[]=one&mytextarea[]=two&mytextarea[]=three
```

My question is if there is a way to make the url look like this instead

```
?mytextarea=one,two,three
```

without using javascript and retrievable in $_GET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without using javascript

No. You would have to use JavaScript for this.

Doing this on server side would be much preferable though - you could process the data there, and then do a header redirect to the final result if you need to show the URL to the user.